# ¿Cómo agrupar un array en Laravel?

Tags: laravel, array

tengo la siguiente consulta y les agradezco de antemano la ayuda:

```
public function listarDiasCheques(){

    $diasCheques = DB::table('db.cuentas')
    ->select(DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(fecha_cheque, "%d") as diaCheque'))
    ->get();

    return ['diasCheques'=>$diasCheques];
}
```

El cual retorna:

```
{"diasCheques":[{"diaCheque":"11"},{"diaCheque":"30"}]}
```

Y lo que necesito es que retorne agrupado:

```
diasCheques = [11, 30]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplemente utilice `pluck` en lugar de `get()`, como parámetro se le pasa el nombre de la columna a obtener, este método retornará una [Collection](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-collections#introduction)

```
$diasCheques = DB::table('db.cuentas')
    ->select(DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(fecha_cheque, "%d") as diaCheque'))
    ->pluck('diaCheque');
```

Comment: Perdón si me equivoco, pero ¿pluck hace tambien la función de `get`? deberia primero obtener los elementos de la base de datos para convertirlos en collections, de tal forma que quede `->get()->pluck('column')`